# Cannot get return value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I know this question has been asked many many times, I've gone through most of them but none resolved my issue

I have a stored procedure called `LoginValidation` which takes 2 parameters, username and password and returns the `user_id` of the corresponding user.

Here is the procedure code:

```
    @username nvarchar(50),
    @password nvarchar(50),
    @userID int output
AS
    SELECT @userID = user_id
    FROM Users_Master 
    WHERE user_name = @username and password = @password;

    RETURN
```

But, when I'm trying to use this procedure in C# the following error occurs:

> Procedure or function 'LoginValidation' expects parameter '@userID', which was not supplied

Here is my C# code:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.Connection = con;

    con.Open();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "LoginValidation";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtmobile.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtpwd.Text;

    SqlParameter returnParm = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    returnParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    string id = returnParm.Value.ToString();

    try
    {
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (SqlException EX)
    {
        string ff = EX.Message;
    }

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Session["name"] = dr["user_name"].ToString();

            lblmsg.Text = "Login successful: " + id;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "Invalid username/password";
    }

    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: A return value is not the same as an output parameter which is what you have, set the direction to output not return.

Comment: You also have `SqlDbType.VarChar` but it shoud be `int`

Comment: Also best practice is to hash your passwords

Comment: You also don't need the Reader stuff, just execute the cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you decide that you want to get output parameter or return value parameter.

1. to get return value parameter. You don't have to pass any extra parameter to stored procedure. just add below lines

   ```
   SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
   returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int id = (int) returnParameter.Value;
   ```
2. to get output parameter. All the steps you done are fine. just replace

   ```
   returnParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
   ```

with

```
  returnParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Comment: Actually in my code I've done several mistakes and these different answers resolved that, but I can consider your answer as the best answer as it covered all the problems of my code. Thanks a lot

Comment: Also, be aware that the **only** datatype that can be **returned** from a stored procedure using the `RETURN` statement is an `int` (or `bigint`), but you **cannot** return a string, datetime or other values - for those, you **must use** `OUTPUT` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `returnParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that you're using an incorrect method `AddWithValue` while passing the data-type. You need to change that to:

```
SqlParameter returnParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@userID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
returnParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Also you need to set the Direction to `Output`

Then you need to read the value **after** executing the query:

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string id = returnParm.Value.ToString();
```

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.ParameterDirection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true):

> **Input**: The parameter is an input parameter.
>
> **InputOutput**: The parameter is capable of both input and output.
>
> **Output**: The parameter is an output parameter.
>
> **ReturnValue**: The parameter represents a return value
> from an operation such as a stored procedure, built-in function, or
> user-defined function.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing mistake. Call

```
string id = returnParm.Value.ToString();
```

after

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```